# Object Oriented Javascript: How to define an object with variable form same object

Tags: javascript, oop

How do I define an object in javascript where the value of one of its key is inherited from another key.

```
a = {

  one : "a",

  two : this.one + 'b'

}

alert(a.two);
```

I know that I can do this by doing something like `a.two = a.one + 'b';`

But is there a cleaner way to keep them coupled within one flower brace

Comment: @FelixKling that's a neat hack, although I'm not sure what the use case for it is ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the properties of an object before it has been created (this includes *during* its creation).

> I know that I can do this by doing something like `a.two = a.one + 'b';`

Yes

> But is there a cleaner way to keep them coupled within one flower brace

No.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it, at least not with a plain object literal.

Only `functions` have a valid `this` reference.  Outside of a function `this` will refer to the global object (i.e. `window`).